# Image src of droppable image in jquery

Tags: jquery

here i want my second and other images to be placed in a trash area  like the first image...the condition are- I have kept images on gallery and i have to make them available in trash area.gallery is draggable and whereas trash is droppable..please help in my code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Simple photo manager</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>
    #gallery {
      float: left;
      width: 65%;
      min-height: 12em;
    }
    .gallery.custom-state-active {
      background: #eee;
    }
    .gallery li {
      float: left;
      width: 96px;
      padding: 0.4em;
      margin: 0 0.4em 0.4em 0;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
    }
    .gallery li h5 {
      margin: 0 0 0.4em;
      cursor: move;
    }
    .gallery li a {
      float: right;
    }
    .gallery li a.ui-icon-zoomin {
      float: left;
    }
    //.gallery li img {
      width: 100%;
      cursor: move;
      display: block;
    }
    .photo1 {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .photo2 {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .photo3 {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .photo4 {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .clr {
      clear: both;
    }
    #trash {
      float: right;
      width: 32%;
      min-height: 18em;
      padding: 1%;
    }
    #trash h4 {
      line-height: 16px;
      margin: 0 0 0.4em;
    }
    #trash h4 .ui-icon {
      float: left;
    }
    #trash .gallery h5 {
      display: none;
    }
    //#trash h4 {
      line-height: 16px;
      margin: 0 0 0.4em;
    }
    //#trash h4 .ui-icon {
      float: left;
    }
    //#trash .gallery h5 {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      var $gallery = $("#gallery");
      var $trash = $("#trash");
      var $photo1 = $("#photo1");
      var $photo2 = $("#photo2");
      var $photo3 = $("#photo3");
      var $photo4 = $("#photo4");



      // let the gallery items be draggable
      $("li", $gallery).draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
        revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
      });

      // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
      $trash.droppable({
        accept: "#gallery > li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          arry = ["images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg", "images/4.jpg", "images/5.jpg"];
          var path = $('img').attr('src');
          var path1 = $('img' + '#c2').attr('src');
          var path2 = $('img' + '#c3').attr('src');
          var path3 = $('img' + '#c4').attr('src');


          if ($("#photo1:has(img.photo1)").length == 0) {

            alert("yes");

            document.getElementById('dc1').src = path;
            $(this).append($(gallery.draggable).clone());

          }
          $(".ui-draggable-dragging").css({
            'display': 'none'
          });



        }



      });


      // let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
      $gallery.droppable({
        accept: "#trash li",
        activeClass: "custom-state-active",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          recycleImage(ui.draggable);
        }
      });


    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">

    <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">

        <img src="images/2.jpg" width="96" height="72" id="c1">


      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">

        <img src="images/3.jpg" width="96" height="72" id="c2">


      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">

        <img src="images/4.jpg" width="96" height="72" id="c3">


      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">

        <img src="images/5.jpg" width="96" height="72" id="c4">


      </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="trash" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default dummy">
      <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Trash</h4>


      <div class="photo1" id="photo1">
        <img src="" width="96" height="72" id="dc1">
      </div>

      <div class="photo2" id="photo2">
        <img src="" width="96" height="72" id="dc2">
      </div>
      <div class="photo3" id="photo3">
        <img src="" width="96" height="72" id="dc3">
      </div>
      <div class="photo4" id="photo4">
        <img src="" width="96" height="72" id="dc4">
      </div>

      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the condition are- I have kept images on gallery and i have to make them available in trash area.gallery is draggable and whereas trash is droppable"* ..? I don't see conditions in there, but statements. Please format the code properly so that it's readable and a working online demo such as a code snippet or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **[working demo here](http://jsbin.com/defiso/2/edit?html,js,output)**

HTML Change: added div.basket in trash.

```
<div id="trash" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default dummy">
  <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Trash</h4>
  <div class="basket"></div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

javascript Change: $trash.droppable=>drop method changed, we can get the dragged image like `ui.draggable.html()`

Code Snippet is here:

```js
    $(function() {
      var $gallery = $("#gallery"),
        $trash = $("#trash");
      // let the gallery items be draggable
      $("li", $gallery).draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
        revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
      });

      // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
      $trash.droppable({
        accept: "#gallery > li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(".basket",this).append(ui.draggable.html());
        }
      });

      // let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
      $gallery.droppable({
        accept: "#trash li",
        activeClass: "custom-state-active",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          recycleImage(ui.draggable);
        }
      });

    });
```

```css
    #gallery {
      float: left;
      width: 65%;
      min-height: 12em;
    }
    .gallery.custom-state-active {
      background: #eee;
    }
    .gallery li {
      float: left;
      width: 96px;
      padding: 0.4em;
      margin: 0 0.4em 0.4em 0;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
    }
    .gallery li h5 {
      margin: 0 0 0.4em;
      cursor: move;
    }
    .gallery li a {
      float: right;
    }
    .gallery li a.ui-icon-zoomin {
      float: left;
    }
    .clr {
      clear: both;
    }
    #trash {
      float: right;
      width: 32%;
      min-height: 18em;
      padding: 1%;
    }
    #trash h4 {
      line-height: 16px;
      margin: 0 0 0.4em;
    }
    #trash h4 .ui-icon {
      float: left;
    }
    #trash .gallery h5 {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Simple photo manager</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
    <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100/100.png" width="96" height="72" id="c1">
      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100/aff.png" width="96" height="72" id="c2">
      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100/abc.png" width="96" height="72" id="c3">
      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100/efa.png" width="96" height="72" id="c4">
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="trash" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default dummy">
      <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Trash</h4>
      <div class="basket"></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: The [intro to stack snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) syas: *"Right now the best way to tell people to do that is to point them to JSFiddle, which is off-site". Saving the code for an SO answer in jsfiddle as well seems to be kind of missing the point...

Comment: @venkata panga : is it possible ,when i drop image at that time alert message will come showing its id i.e id of image..and image will drop in droppable area..

Comment: yes you can do like `alert(ui.draggable.children('img').attr('id'))`

Comment: @VenkataPanga Hmm.. I guess you didn't understood what I was trying to say... StackOVerflow introduced `Stack Snippets` So that the code won't be *off-sourced* to other sites (*The code stays in their server* ;)

Comment: OK got it, You mean we can stay with SO code-snippets all the time.

Comment: @venkata panga : hello!I am in need to make slider to be droppable.can it is possible to do that.Now i have done image to be draggable.And for drop function i haven't any idea..Could you suggest me where i am wrong..or how can i write drop function to make slider acts like a droppable.

Comment: @Ritasahoo show me your code with demo. That helps us understand the behavior.

Comment: we have been discussed the code earlier.In that code i want to add some functionality,gallery will be draggable and trash will be droppable.But know i have used to append the clone from droppable area i.e trash,that my trash is now works as draggable that means in droppable area clones can be dragged.And also my draggable images should be put on the slider that works as a droppable area.My slider is also works as a droppable area,it accepts draggable image from trash.But,where i am facing problem is that clone won't slide.

Comment: And css that i have used,is similar to css for trash.